# Pivot table not showing the Data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I am new to SQL Server, I am facing the problem to display the data using pivot tables.

My table structure is like this:

```
 UserName    VisitedDate    Amount   Visted
    bbb     2012-07-05      200       1
    bbb     2012-06-03      300       3
    ccc     2012-04-15      500       5
    ccc     2012-06-30      600       3
```

I searched a lot and found something useful as:

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @ColumnNames VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @BeginDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
declare @AAmount varchar(1000)

SET @BeginDate = '2012-4-1'
SET @EndDate = '2013-3-30'
SET @ColumnNames = ''
set @AAmount = ''

WHILE @BeginDate <= @EndDate
BEGIN
 SET @ColumnNames = @ColumnNames + ',[' + DateName(month,@BeginDate) + '_' +     Cast(Year(@BeginDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ']'
SET @AAmount = @AAmount + ',[' +'Amount'+ DateName(month,@BeginDate) + '_' +   Cast(Year(@BeginDate) AS VARCHAR(4)) + ']'
SET @BeginDate = DateAdd(Month, 1, @BeginDate)
END
IF Len(@ColumnNames) > 0
SET @ColumnNames = Right(@ColumnNames, Len(@ColumnNames) - 1)

PRINT @ColumnNames
IF Len(@AAmount) > 0
SET @AAmount = Right(@AAmount, Len(@AAmount) - 1)

PRINT @AAmount


SET @Sql = '
WITH U AS
(
  SELECT UserName, DateName(month,Visited_Date) + ''_'' + Cast(Year(Visited_Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS VisitedMonth,Amount,DateName(month,Visited_Date) + ''_'' + Cast(Year(Visited_Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS VisitedMonth1,Visited
    FROM Users 
)
SELECT  *
FROM U 

PIVOT (
SUM(Amount) FOR VisitedMonth IN (' + @ColumnNames + ')
) AS P1
PIVOT (
SUM(Visited) FOR VisitedMonth1 IN (' + @AAmount + ')
) AS  pivotable'


 EXEC (@Sql)
```

and the result from this query is this:

```
UserName AprilAmount_2012  MayAmt_2012 JuneAmt_2012 April_2012  May_2012    June_2012
bbb      NULL              NULL         NULL        NULL           NULL      NULL
bbb      NULL              NULL         300         NULL           NULL      NULL
ccc      NULL              NULL         600         NULL           NULL      NULL
ccc      500               NULL         NULL        NULL           NULL      NULL
```

**Please Note that amt. in header is Amount**

Now my problems are:

1. for 3 columns in the table it shows the data but I tried to add one more column visited then it is not displaying the expected result....
2. I also want to rearrange the columns as :

   ```
   UserName AprilAmount_2012 April_2012 MayAmt_2012  May_2012   JuneAmt_2012    June_2012
   bbb      NULL              NULL           NULL       NULL          NULL         NULL
   bbb      NULL              NULL           NULL       NULL          300          3
   ccc      NULL              4              NULL       NULL          600          NULL
   ccc      500               NULL           NULL       NULL          NULL         5
   ```
3. I also want the unique names to be displayed...

Please help me or tell me the way so that I can find the solution.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Add `PRINT @sql` to see and then debug the generated script.

Comment: @AndriyM: Thanks for the time given, I use the Print statement suggested by u then i got the query as:    `WITH U AS
(
    SELECT UserName, DateName(month,Visited_Date) + '_' + Cast(Year(Visited_Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS VisitedMonth,DateName(month,Visited_Date) + '_' + Cast(Year(Visited_Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS VisitedMonth1,Amount,Visited
    FROM Users 
)
SELECT  *
FROM U 
 Pivot(
 SUM(Visited) for VisitedMonth1 IN([AmountApril_2012],[AmountMay_2012],[AmountJune_2012])
 ) as P
PIVOT (
    SUM(Amount) FOR VisitedMonth IN ([April_2012],[May_2012],[June_2012])
) AS P1`
m not figured out the error

Comment: @AndriyM: Can u give me the Example where we can use 2 or more pivots so that i can get more idea about it and able to solve my problem.  Thanks in advance

Comment: I had never seen queries with double pivoting until encountering your post, actually. If I were to "inherit" someone else's non-working script like yours, I would try to do just what I suggested to you, i.e. I would print the generated script **and debug it**. By *debugging* in this case I understand running this script *and/or its parts* in a query window of Management Studio. It would be hard for me to suggest something more specific at this point, because I don't have data to try your script on.

Comment: You should probably start with trying to come up with a *static* (i.e. normal) query that has two PIVOTs. And if you aren't really acquainted with PIVOTs, then you should start even earlier, with a single PIVOT. Once that stage is clear for you, move on to the next one: two PIVOTs, then dynamic script with PIVOT, then dynamic script with two PIVOTs. That may seem as a hard way, and I'm sorry about that, but if you lack necessary knowledge, you *need* to gain it. And what better way to gain it if not by trial and error?

Comment: I mean, you can still ask questions, like you do, the point is, you shouldn't be trying to ask questions *about many things at a time*. For you indeed are asking about at least two different things in this question: two PIVOTs in a single query *and* issues with dynamic double-PIVOT queries.

Comment: @AndriyM ok, will again start from scratch like you suggested and get back to you if found any Problem....thanks for response and time given to me..

Comment: @AndriyM thanks, only because of u m able to get the new concept and almost near to the solution i want....

Comment: I'm glad that you could see sense in what I said and that it worked out well for you. Whenever you need help, feel free to post a question. It's all right if your question is *hard*, just try not to make it overly *complex*. Basically, just try to follow these simple guidelines about asking questions: [ask].